# How to reset dataTable filter via server side

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My main jsf include 2 jsf’s where in each one of them there is a table with filtering option.

this is a short example from the main:

```
  <h:panelGroup id="b1">
                <p:commandButton
                    value="exe"
                    actionListener="#{bean.handle}"
                    rendered="#{bean.render}"
                    update=":mainForm:panel1,:mainForm:panel2">
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

    <ui:include src="table1.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="table2.xhtml" />
```

The problem is that I need to remove the filters when changing the view between the 2 tables 
I can’t use the client side via clearFilters since I have 2 tables:

```
<p:commandButton
oncomplete="table1Widget.clearFilters() ????"
```

so I was thinking that the best place will on the server side via handle method but the filter list is empty and also the table

```
DataTable dt1 = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("mainForm: .... ");
```

How can i reset the filters ?

Thanks

Comment: Please give much information for your problem it seems to be incomplete to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 datatables at my session. I didn't understand reason but when i use `dt1.reset()` it resets both of them.

I tried

```
dt1 = new DataTable();
```

and it solved my problem.

Note: `dt1.reset()` works when i tried with 1 datatable.

Comment: Weird behaviour and bad 'solution'...  doing a 'new' on a JSF component is always bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following on that datatable that you have:

1. `dt1..setFilters(null);` Will get rid of the datatable filter values
2. `dt1.reset()` will also reset the datatable to a virgin state

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Primefaces current** helper (version 6.2) to execute clearFilters on the server side as below:

```
PrimeFaces current = PrimeFaces.current();
current.executeScript("PF('dataTableWidget').clearFilters()");
```